# How to accessing a business bean via JNDI from a library?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4

I've written my own authentification realm for Glassfish server 4. As the reference says, I've placed the jar with the realm class and login module in `domains/[domain]/lib` and everything works. Now I want to access a business bean from this realm library. The business bean is located in the EJB part of the project. But it fails permanently. I tried:

```
    try {
        Object object = InitialContext.doLookup("java:global/My-Demo-ejb/A");
        System.out.println("=====> Obj: " + object);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Looking up failed:");
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In this case my project is named "My-Demo" and the EJB subproject is named "My-Demo-ejb". The Interface "A" looks like:

```
@Remote
public interface A {
...
}
```

and there is also an implementation:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class AB implements A {
...
}
```

But everytime I try this, the exception `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException` occurs. Also trying to place the Bean in the WAR part fails with the JNDI string `java:global/My-Demo-war/A`

Could you see any mistake?

**EDIT:** it is working, iff one uses the JNDI string `java:global/Demo/Demo-ejb/AB!de.login.security.AB`. Isn't there an easier way than referencing the complete path to the package and why doesn't it work with the interface name instead (A instead of AB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use application server dependent JNDI name like:

```
@Stateless(name="etc")
```

And you can access it:

```
InitialContext.doLookup("etc")
```

But this only works in glassfish.